# What should we do with identification questions that ask for multiple series?

Tags: discussion, questions, identification-questions

What should be done with questions like [**this one**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7692/274) (I recall another but can't find it, it may have been deleted) where the OP requests identification of multiple series? It's possible the OP (hypothetically) does not know that the provided images are from different series, but should we allow these kind of questions, or should they be split into multiple?

Pros of keeping it as one question:

- OP receives only one answer for their inquiry.
- We can keep identification request counts down by keeping them grouped together (by OP/time of asking).

Pros of splitting it up:

- More helpful to future users.
- Easier to search for a specific question/answer pair.
- Questions are less likely to be defined as "too broad."
- Users who only know one of the multiple given series can provide an answer.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One question per question please. That's the policy everywhere, that's the policy here as well.

If you encounter this, I propose editing to remove all other questions, and leaving a comment for OP to ask his extra questions one at a time.

We need to stretch the line somewhere, this is it.

Comment: I assume this can be handled by requesting the OP edit the question, and if not simply closing it as too broad? As in, should we be editing the post ourselves?

Comment: @Eric: I'll expand my answer. I propose editing to remove all other questions, and leaving a comment for OP to ask his extra questions one at a time.

Comment: I agree, we should also let the OP know that he can see his original post via the edit link. I know *I* didn't know how to see edits when I first started.