# Asking multiple manga chapter where an anime end

Tags: discussion

Is it okay if I put more than 1 anime in a single question or should I separate them? Something like [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14174/what-manga-chapter-does-gokukoku-no-brynhildr-anime-end-on) but with more than 1 anime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should separate them, reason is because separate questions are better for sites like google to keep track of.

Its related to this question: [What should we do with identification questions that ask for multiple series?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/what-should-we-do-with-identification-questions-that-ask-for-multiple-series?rq=1)

Comment: Will I not get flag for asking same topics but different animes on different questions?

Comment: you will get down votted and or have the question closed for being too broad. just write one question for each series and you will be fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel You shouldn't need to ask about a lot all at once. Once you get an answer for one series you're interested in, go read it. Once you finish, you can come back and ask about the next one.